# formatting bytes string into another bytes string

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, string-formatting, python-3.4

I have a list of bytes strings that I try for format into another string, which in turn I convert to bytes, looks something like this:

```
byte_string = b'text'
fmt = 'this is the text: %s'
fmt_string = bytes(fmt % byte_string, 'utf-8')
```

but if I print `fmt_string` I get this

> b"this is the text: b'text'"

I know that in python3.5 I can do this:

```
b'this is the text: %s' % b'text'
```

and receive:

> b'this is the text: text'

is there a way to do the same with python3.4?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use formatting on `bytes` objects in Python 3.4 or below. Your options are to upgrade to 3.5 or newer, or not use formatting on bytes.

In Python 3.5 and up, you need to make `fmt` a bytes object; you'd use a bytes literal, and apply the `%` operator to *that*:

```
fmt = b'this is the text: %s'
fmt_string = fmt % byte_string
```

Alternatively, encode the template *first*, then apply the values:

```
fmt = 'this is the text: %s'
fmt_string = bytes(fmt, 'utf-8') % byte_string
```

If upgrading is not an option, but your bytes values have a consistent encoding, decode first, then encode again:

```
fmt = 'this is the text: %s'
fmt_string = bytes(fmt % byte_string.decode('utf-8'), 'utf-8')
```

If you can't decode your `bytes` values, then your only remaining option is to concatenate `bytes` objects:

```
fmt = b'this is the text: '  # no placeholder
fmt_string = fmt + byte_string
```

This will require multiple parts if there is text after the placeholders, of course.

Comment: python3.4 doesn't let you format into bytes object: `fmt = b'the text is: %s' fmt % b'text' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-114011e9215e> in <module>()
----> 1 fmt % b'text'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'bytes'`

Comment: Oh crumbs. In that case your options are to using grade to 3.5, or decode both the format and value, interpolate then reencode, or to not use formatting (use concatenation instead).