# Byte string visualization in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to work with byte strings, but it is not easy for me because of the automatic process of getting the corresponding values to my bytes as letters/digits. An example:

```py
>>> b'\x45'
b'E' 

b'\x50\x64'
b'Pd'
```

But I would like to read it as I write it (b'\x45' in the first case, for instance).

Is is possible?

Comment: You might also be helped by this Q & A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116866/formatting-bytes-string-into-another-bytes-string

Comment: no, but you ould maybe just look at `list(data)`